# Upgrading Eclipse from Studio 2 to 3 gets all kinds of dependency errors related to Studio 2

Tags: aptana

Upgrading Eclipse from Studio 2 to 3 gets all kinds of dependency errors related to Studio 2 (bunch of gibberish for me to decipher in the details:

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.0.9.201202140953-7E777Q7HFGVBKBSEW7S_Iz0JktqM (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.0.9.201202140953-7E777Q7HFGVBKBSEW7S_Iz0JktqM)
  Software currently installed: Aptana Studio 2.0.4.1268158907-5-7757FJ5398991HN1HIHtdfxN7r (com.aptana.ide.feature.studio.feature.group 2.0.4.1268158907-5-7757FJ5398991HN1HIHtdfxN7r)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Aptana SecureFTP Library 2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676 (com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.jar 2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676)
    Aptana Subscription Libraries 2.0.2.1257900677-3-12368A11788 (com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.jar 2.0.2.1257900677-3-12368A11788)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 Core 3.0.9.1329151902-BJ7F8NBTEBQakdyRh1DC34EVnIM5 (com.aptana.feature.feature.group 3.0.9.1329151902-BJ7F8NBTEBQakdyRh1DC34EVnIM5)
    To: com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.group [2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 Plugin 3.0.9.201202140953-7E777Q7HFGVBKBSEW7S_Iz0JktqM (com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group 3.0.9.201202140953-7E777Q7HFGVBKBSEW7S_Iz0JktqM)
    To: com.aptana.feature.feature.group [3.0.9.1329151902-BJ7F8NBTEBQakdyRh1DC34EVnIM5]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Subscription Libraries 2.0.2.1257900677-3-12368A11788 (com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.group 2.0.2.1257900677-3-12368A11788)
    To: com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.jar [2.0.2.1257900677-3-12368A11788]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana SecureFTP Library 2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676 (com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.group 2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676)
    To: com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.jar [2.0.2.1317770565-3-12428881676]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana SecureFTP Support 2.0.4.1268103313-77-7878BMSG5BHEI04023479B228 (com.aptana.ide.feature.secureftp.feature.group 2.0.4.1268103313-77-7878BMSG5BHEI04023479B228)
    To: com.aptana.ide.feature.libraries.subscription.feature.group [2.0.2.1257900677-3-12368A11788]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 2.0.4.1268158907-5-7757FJ5398991HN1HIHtdfxN7r (com.aptana.ide.feature.studio.feature.group 2.0.4.1268158907-5-7757FJ5398991HN1HIHtdfxN7r)
    To: com.aptana.ide.feature.secureftp.feature.group [2.0.4.1268103313-77-7878BMSG5BHEI04023479B228]

Answer (score 0):

Studio 3 is a major release with quite difficult underlying code from Studio 2, and you would need to uninstall Studio 2 first and then install Studio 3 instead of updating.